# Convertir String en matriz

Tags: java, array, string, matrices

Tengo este string en Java

```
String str = "a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, , n, o, p";
```

Y necesito convertirlo en una matriz donde se especifican las filas y las columnas. Es decir:

**3 por 3**

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

O

**2 por 8**

```
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  i
j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q
```

---

Este es mi codigo, que siempre retorna null

```
public static String Format(String str, int rows, int columns)
    {
        try
        {
            String[][] matrix = new String[rows][columns];
            String[][] arr = Arrays.stream(str.substring(2, str.length() - 2).split("\\],\\["))
            .map(e -> Arrays.stream(e.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
            .toArray(String[]::new)).toArray(String[][]::new);

            String append = "|\t", result;

             for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) 
             {
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) 
                {
                    matrix[i][j] = arr[i][j];
                }
             }

              for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
               for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
                append += matrix[i][j] + "\t";
                }}

            result = append + "|";
            append = "|\t";
            return result;

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: La pregunta desafortunadamente ne está muy clara para mi. Cuándo diga `2 x 3` y emita 2 líneas y 8 columnas ahí está una contradicción. Podría aclarar por favor ?

Comment: Fue un error, pregunta editada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pareciera que el error está en como convertís el string en un array para rellenar la matriz, aquí usé un vector (array unidimensional) lo voy iterando y si se pasa del length completa con *. También el formateo de la salida estaba medio extraño (append) así que lo ajuste para que ponga un | al empezar la fila y un | mas un salto de línea al cerrar la fila

```
public static String FormatMatrix(String str, int rows, int columns) {
 try {
  String[][] matrix = new String[rows][columns];
  String[] arr = str.split("\\s*,\\s*");

  int k = 0;
  int s = arr.length;

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
   for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
    matrix[i][j] = (k < s) ? arr[k] : "*";
    ++k;
   }
  }

  String append = "", result;

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
   append += "|\t";
   for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
    append += matrix[i][j] + "\t";
   }
   append += "|\n";
  }
  result = append;
  return result;

 } catch (Exception e) {
  return null;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ahora que la pregunta se ha actualizado para clarificar, me gustaría ofrecer una respuesta un poco más elaborada.

Propongo usar las herramientas que Java nos da:

- Utilisar una clase diseñada que se puede utilizar y mejorar con el tiempo segùn los requerimientos. En este ejemplo creé una clase `MatrixReader`para leer una cadena de carácteres y convertirla en una matriz.
- Así se puede más facilmente comprobar haciendo unit tests o cambiar el diseño en muchos casos
- Utilisar `Scanner` para desglosar la cadena de carácteres facilmente. De mañera general dicen que un buen programador de Java sabe utilisar las herramientas del estandár que existen (sin reinventar la rueda); elegí `Scanner` porque es fácil de usar y `StringBuilder` por la eficiencia (`String` es inmutable, `StringBuffer` es [thread safe](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seguridad_en_hilos) pero para un programa simple `StringBuilder` es suficiente y eficiente)
- Falta una especificación más clara. La relación entre la cadena de carácteres y la matriz tendría que ser más detallada: Que pasa si tengo `a, b, c` con una matriz de `2 x 2` ? Que pasa si tengo `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j` con una matriz de `2 x 6`? (En este ejemplo la lectura se termina cuando no hay más carácteres o no hay espacio en la matriz; ven las dos últimas matrizes en el ejemplo)

También me gustaría darle feedback en cuanto a su estilo:

- `try/catch` es una buena herramienta para tratar excepciones pero tampoco es una buena solución en muchos casos que veo en programas Java. En este caso supongo que quiere evitar una excepción accediendo al vector (`ArrayOutOfBoundsException`). Se puede hacer pero no estoy seguro si es necesario. Simplemente evitar que se accede fuera del vector es suficiente (y una buena espacificación ayuda como dicho antes); quizás mi ejemplo puede inspirarle un poco. `try/catch` es aconsejado en situaciones que no se pueden controlar, pero en este caso podríamos en mi opinion)
- Su código siempre retorna `null` por el `try/catch`. Es el único lugar que retorna `null` en su código. Espero que ve que el uso del `try/catch` tampoco es una solución para todas las situaciones. Quería evitar una excepción pero nos cuesta tiempo ahora analizando porque no funciona el código.
- El uso de una clase `String` para representar un carácter es posible pero no lo veo eficaz. En mi ejemplo quería mostrar que la repsentación interna (en la clase) puede ser más fácil y eficaz (`char`) sin renunciar a la necesidad de convertir y/o emitir en otra representación (`String`)

_

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Parametros
        String str = "a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p";

        //Lectura y conversion
        MatrixReader reader = new MatrixReader(str, 2, 3);
        reader.convertStringToMatrix();
        reader.printMatrix();

        reader = new MatrixReader(str, 3, 3);
        reader.convertStringToMatrix();
        reader.printMatrix();

        reader = new MatrixReader(str, 2, 8);
        reader.convertStringToMatrix();
        System.out.println("Emitir matriz " + reader.getRows() + " x " + reader.getCols());
        System.out.print(reader.getStringMatrix());

        reader = new MatrixReader(str, 3, 8);
        reader.convertStringToMatrix();
        System.out.println("Emitir matriz " + reader.getRows() + " x " + reader.getCols());
        System.out.print(reader.getStringMatrix());

        return;
    }
}

class MatrixReader {

    private String str;
    private int rows;
    private int cols;
    private char matriz[][];

    public MatrixReader(String str, int rows, int columns) {
        this.str = str;
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = columns;
        matriz = new char[rows][columns];
    }

    public int getCols() {
        return cols;
    }

    public int getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public char[][] convertStringToMatrix() {

        //Definir la cadena de caracteres a procesar y especificar el separador
        Scanner in = new Scanner(str);
        in.useDelimiter(", ");

        //llenar la matriz
        int r = 0;
        int c = 0;
        char caracter;
        //hay más carácteres para leer y estamos dentro de la matriz
        while (in.hasNext() && r < matriz.length && c < matriz[r].length) {
            caracter = in.next().charAt(0); //leer una cadena de caracteres (tamaño 1) y extraer el primer caracter
            matriz[r][c] = caracter;
            c++;
            if (c == matriz[r].length) {
                r++;
                c = 0;
            }
        }

        in.close();

        return matriz;
    }

    //emitir en salida estandar
    public void printMatrix() {
        System.out.println("Emitir matriz " + rows + " x " + cols);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                System.out.print(" " + matriz[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    //convertir matriz de carácteres en cadena de carácteres
    public String getStringMatrix() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(rows * cols);//capacidad inicial es r x c
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                s.append(' ').append(matriz[i][j]);
            }
            s.append(System.lineSeparator());//separado de línea depende del sistema
        }
        return s.toString();
    }

}
```